# Google Appmaker createItem failing with could not select element

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a temporary table where I let the user copy the record that needs to be edited. Once the edit is complete, I copy it back.

I am getting an error when I am trying to copy the original record to temporary table for editing. Here's the code I am using

```
  console.log('copyOriginalToTemp ' + tempRecord.ID + ' options ' + JSON.stringify(options));
  var myCreateDatasource = app.datasources.RadiosTemp.modes.create;
  console.log('# of items in myCreateDatasource ' + myCreateDatasource.items.length);
  var draft = myCreateDatasource.item;
  draft.BatchId = options.BatchId ;
  draft.County = tempRecord.County ;
  ... // lot of assignments
  console.log('About to create item ');
  myCreateDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) {
    console.log('Creating the Item ' + createdRecord._key);
    app.datasources.RadiosTemp.query.filters.BatchId._equals = options.BatchId;
     .....
});
```

Error message tells me that newly created item cannot be selected but I have no idea why?. If I change the datasource to Manual Save, I get the same error with no key since it is in Manual save mode.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem or if you just forgot to include your very last line of code. But with the code you have here you are missing '});' as the very last line of code. Still not sure if that will solve your problem though or not.

Comment: They are there, I just did not copy the whole section for brevity.

Comment: Any solutions ?

Comment: It fixed itself. No idea why or what but I noticed that in some cases, the SQL that gets generated when syncing the db was not correct. Also in some cases, even though SQL was correct (using auto increment), the back end still did not work...